# Было полночь

Tags: согласование

Допустимо ли сказать  *Был**о** полночь*, если имеется в виду время, 12 часов ночи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это не безличное предложение, сказуемое согласуется с подлежащим, вернее координируется - полночь что делала? - была.

Но: было за полночь, было много времени, было позднее время.

Answer (score 2):

> Допустимо ли сказать Было полночь...

**Когда-то так говорили**. Несколько примеров можно найти здесь:

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C%22&tbm=bks

**Сейчас так не говорят.** Говорят -- **была полночь**. Примеры см. здесь:

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C%22&tbm=bks